# Update div data with AJAX every second

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have used Ajax to fetch the data for the div every second in case there is new inserted data but this causes the server to crash in about 10 seconds. How can I write a script to refresh div every second without it using so much resources.

Here is the code with the complete function but it still seems to give errors

```
function checkForMessages(friends_id, id) {


$.ajax({
    url: "../fetch_chat.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "current_user="+friends_id+"&friends_id="+id,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#chatContainer').html(data);
        var div = document.getElementById('chat_post_container');
        div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;


    },
    complete: function(data){

        checkForMessages(friends_id, id);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('ERROR');
    }
});


}
```

Comment: Thats broad subject of various techniques like long pooling and push. But i think if your server can stand 1 request per second, then you really ought to change server. Could you post more details ?

Comment: you should use `signalr` in case of `asp.net` to use push technique so whenever new data arrives, then only div is updated. updating with same data repeatedly every second will consume your resource.

Answer (score 2):

try to check last request is complete or not, then after one sec call next Ajax request.
This will balance load on server.
If possible for refreshing use signalR.

Or
you can use set interval
eg

```
setInterval(function(){ 
//code goes here that will be run every 5 seconds. }, 5000);
```

For ajax request use add async:false so request will be complete asynchronously.

Comment: How do I check whether the last request is complete or not?

Answer (score 1):

You should do this with help of Socket.io, or React.js, technology is changing, so we should change our way of doing things too.

this might help you a lot.

https://codeforgeek.com/2015/03/real-time-app-socket-io/

Comment: Thanks for the advice